# preimage pallet is added, it shows up in extrinsics > preimage, but does not show up in chain > storage > preimage

Tags: parachain, runtime

Added preimage pallet [here](https://github.com/kabocha-network/parachain/blob/kab-release-v0.2.6-soupcan-new-xcm/runtime/src/lib.rs), (because it seems to be a necessity in the > polkadot-0.9.37)

It shows up in `developer > extrinsics > preimage
[image: Screenshot]

but does not show up in `query > preimage`...
[image: Screenshot]

I have added the necessary changes to the `runtime/src/lib.rs` but I'm not sure what's missing?

Do I need to add a runtime api? But I don't see it added in other examples...

you can view it in [polkadot-js-apps here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fsoupcan1.jelliedowl.com#/chainstate)

and here is the [branch](https://github.com/kabocha-network/parachain/blob/kab-release-v0.2.6-soupcan-new-xcm/runtime/src/lib.rs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the storage visible, you also need to add `Storage`, when you instantiate the pallet in the `construct_runtime!` macro, i.e.:

```rust
Preimage: pallet_preimage::{Pallet, Event<T>, Call, Storage} = 19,
```